# SimpleMembership without external logins?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I have just started with some articles about SimpleMembership and I really like it, but I would like it more without the external logins (Facebook, Twitter, OAuth). They're not enabled by default, but in almost every account model or view there is a part for the external logins.

Is it possible to "remove" or "disable" this feature and is there any article aobut it?

Comment: You'd have to remove those in the source https://github.com/anderly/SimpleMembership.Mvc3. If they aren't hurting anything I think you probably don't want to go the route of maintaining your own port with those features left out

Comment: So basically, it's not a good idea... Then, I'll try to "hide" the access to the external login by "not rendering" the views. I just don't like the "schizophrenic" effect with external logins, local accounts, local passwords and usernames, etc ... But thanks far the help ;).